# how to use if else statement in php/Html programming languages

Tags: php

I am new in PhP. i am trying to use if/else statement to request for (include 'user_index_Big_Data.php';) with different inputs.

when I run the code it will output all the .php forms. but i just want it to output just one form.

```
<html>
<head>
    <LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>



<form action="" method="post">
    <h1>Enter Key word to search</h1>
    <p>Search <input type="text" name="username" placeholder='e.g. big data, Big Data'></p>
 <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$user = ("Big Data" || "big data" or "Big data" or "BIG DATA" or "big data analytics" or "BIG DATA ANALYTICS" 
        or "big data analysis");
$user1 = ("machine learning" || "MACHINE LEARNING" or "Machine Learning" or "Machine learning");
$user2 = ("Data center" || "Efficient Energy" or "Renewal Energy" or "Multi-Agents");
//$pass = "itsme";
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if($_POST["username"] == $user ) 
include 'user_index_Big_Data.php';}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      if($_POST["username"] == $user1 ) 
           include 'user_index_machine_Learning.php';

  } 

  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      if($_POST["username"] == $user3 ) 
           include 'Energy.php';
         } 
  else {
        echo "Incorrect Key Word";
   } 
      ?>
```

please i want the code to output just one form. but it outputs all the forms. it echos all the results of the forms.

Comment: `$user = ("Big Data" || "big data" or …` - this will just result in `$user` having the boolean value `true`. You can not do a comparison(?) like that, this is completely wrong. If you want to check if the POST parameter is one of multiple possible values - then put those values into an array, and use `in_array` to check.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the various key-words to arrays you can test for a match using `in_array` ~ though there is no need to include all possible uppercase/lowercase variants, just cast supplied user data to lowercase etc

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php


            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['type'] ) ){
                /* Process secondary form submission - do whatever needs to be done with secondary forms */
                ob_clean();
                $_POST['time']=time();
                exit( json_encode( $_POST ) );
            }


            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['username'] ) ){
                /* Process primary form to select secondary form */
                $file=false;

                $user=array('big data','big data analytics');
                $user1=array('machine learning');
                $user2=array('data center','efficient energy','renewal energy','multi-agents');         


                $username=trim( strtolower( urldecode( $_POST['username'] ) ) );

                if( in_array( $username, $user ) )$file='user_index_Big_Data.php';
                if( in_array( $username, $user1 ) )$file='user_index_machine_Learning.php';
                if( in_array( $username, $user2 ) )$file='Energy.php';



                if( $file ){
                    if( file_exists( $file ) )require $file;
                    else printf( 'Unable to find file: "%s" to suit username "%s"', $file, $_POST['username'] );
                } else {
                    printf( 'Incorrect Key Word: "%s"', $_POST['username'] );               
                }
            }

        ?>


        <form method='post'>
            <h1>Enter Key word to search</h1>
            <p>Search <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='e.g. big data, Big Data'></p>
            <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search'></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The other, secondarary, forms:

```
<?php

    /* Big Data : user_index_Big_Data.php */

?>
<form name='big-data' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='type' value='big data' />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>

<?php

    /* machine learning : user_index_machine_Learning.php */

?>
<form name='machine-learning' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='type' value='machine learning' />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>

<?php

    /* Energy : energy.php */

?>
<form name='energy' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='type' value='Energy' />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Very Big Thanks to you.  i am so happy for this correction. Thanks.